# Editing Legend Text in Carto ("Other")

Tags: carto, legend

I'm working on a map that has nine unique categories and Carto adds an "Other" category to the legend. There is no other data outside of my nine unique categories and I can't get rid of Other label on the legend.

[image: Map image]

Do you have any advice for how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a workaround that could solve your issue. As shown in the gif below, if you can change your legend from `Category` to `Custom`, the `Others` category will be removed.

[image]